# Windows server 2008 R2 doesn't let install web deploy and IIS 10

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, iis

I'm trying to install [web deploy 3.6](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy) and IIS 10 on a windows server 2008 R2, but after I install those two and restart the server, they don't show up in the programs, I just see IIS Express in the program files folder.

This server already had IIS 7.

So why it doesn't install them properly and how can I get them to install and work?

PS: I can't find any of those things they show here in the images: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis, how come?